# Eclipse plugin. Browser in Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to add Browser object into editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following example.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTBrowser.htm

Answer (score 0):

Window/Show Views/Other then select "Internal Web Browser"

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an eclipse plug-in, try this:

```
int style = IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EDITOR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.LOCATION_BAR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.STATUS;
IWebBrowser browser = WorkbenchBrowserSupport.getInstance().createBrowser(style, "MyBrowserID", "MyBrowserName", "MyBrowser Tooltip");
browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
```

Source: http://blog.roweware.com/2007/07/24/open-url-in-eclipse/

Comment: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser()